# How to detect if it is Windows 8 using Installshield?

Tags: installshield, windows-8

I am creating a new installer for Windows using InstallShield. I am new to InstallShield. In the installer I am to install one component only on windows 8.

So what should I put in the install condition for that component? Can I use `VersionNT` or `MsiNTProductType`.

However I could not find the value of these variables for Windows 8. Is there any other way of doing this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this condition: **VersionNT > 601**  ?

Comment: For clarification, this will allow the component on versions of Windows after Windows 7. I agree this is likely to be the desired behavior, but the question asked for "only on windows 8". This is likely to be *VersionNT=602* instead, but I wouldn't trust the new version number until at least beta.

Comment: One could download the OS and install it to log an install and find out.  Also, FWIW, Stefan Krueger recently tweeted a link statint that Win8 will be Win 6.2 which in MSI is 602 as you indicated. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-116T

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. I got it now. This URL[link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370556(v=vs.85).aspx) provided the details.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I usually avoid using OS Version Properties like this in conditions.  What I usually try to do is ask myself what is it about that platform that is really important to me.   Do I need a certain version of IIS?  Do I need a certain service that's new in that version?  Do I need a higher version of the .NET framework and so on.

Then I write a search and condition based on that relationship.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I got the answer.

Comment: VersionNT is too tightly coupled in my opinion.  Your component has a dependency on something new in Windows 8 and in 8.x+ it could be gone.   Write installers that stand the test of time.

Comment: Yes. You are right. However we had some component that is specific to Windows 8 only.